# Enable floating column width in tabular

Tags: tables, floats, tabularx

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.3mm}
    \begin{tabular}[0mm]{cccc}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c} &
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c} \\
    A text & A long B text & C text & D text
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It produces:

[image: result]

Note "A long B text" streches the table, and ruin the first row.

I would like the column width to be "floating", i.e.

- for first row: the four figures stay closely, like image "C" to image "C";
- for second row: "A long B text" has flexiable larger width than other columns, and at the same time align with first row.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not work with \begin{tabular}{p{...cm}p{...cm}p{...cm}p{...cm}} for row 1 and using @{\extracolsep{\fill}} for row 2?

Comment: @aerioeus I have tried I may not get the idea... Could you please hint more on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think setting a box with 0 width for the long description is enough.

```
\documentclass[preview,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.3mm}
    \begin{tabular}[0mm]{cccc}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c} &
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-c} \\
    A text & \makebox[0pt]{A long B text} & C text & D text
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]